# Lag (Hmisc) with a shift argument defined in another column R

Tags: r, dplyr, lag, hmisc

To make it simple, i would like a column C to be equal to the
   Lag of a column B, with the shift argument depending on the integers
   in the column A, so I want:

```
   A | B | C  
   0 | 5 | 5 
   2 | 6 | NA 
   3 | 7 | NA 
   2 | 8 | 6
```

I tried:

```
library(dplyr)
library(Hmisc)
data <- mutate(data, 
    C= Lag(B, shift=as.integer(A)),
```

but it doesn't work, i get NAs only, it's probably a type issue but
   i'm not sure as even with the as.integer it doesn't work, Does
   someone have any idea why it doesn't work?

Thanks a lot

Comment: are you sure your output is correct? I think it should be `5, NA, NA, 6` Try `diag(sapply(df$A, function(i) lag(df$B, i)))`

Comment: Oh yes, i made a mistake, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

`lag` from `dplyr` also has the shift argument, so no need to load another package. One way to do it would be,

```
library(dplyr)
df$C <- diag(sapply(df$A, function(i) lag(df$B, i)))
df
#  A B  C
#1 0 5  5
#2 2 6 NA
#3 3 7 NA
#4 2 8  6
```

Comment: I get the error "n must be a single positive integer", even when i add as.integer before i

Comment: do you have any negative integers in `df$A`? Can you share the `str(data)`?

Comment: Those are all num, but yes i have negative integers in df$A, with Lag (Hmisc) negative integers take the forward values instead of the values before! And zeros seem to be a problem too, when i dont have any negative values, but i have zeros, i get the error : Error in if (n == 0) return(x) : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: How do you want to treat those? Would it be ok if you converted negatives to positives? (i.e. `diag(sapply(abs(df$A), function(i) lag(df$B, i)))`  As for 0 it seems to be working on the example you shared.

Comment: I need to take the forward values so I cant convert from negative to positive,  maybe i need to find something else than lag

Comment: I mean take the values from the rows that are after and not before

Comment: I found a solution:  i did df$C <- apply(as.data.frame(df$A), 1, function(i){
    nth(df$B, i)
  })  And i changed my input so that i dont have negative values anymore

Answer (score 0):

Solution: 
The shift argument does not seem to take a column values as integers, 
so i did it in another way:

```
df$C <- apply(as.data.frame(df$A), 1, function(i){ 
    nth(df$B, i) 
})
```

It takes the nth value of B, with n being in the A col

(Thanks a lot for helping me Sotos)